# Grails 2.0.3 Integration test failing for strange reason(save() on domain model not available for second call to setup method)

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I've recently begun playing around with Grails 2.0 in earnest but I've hit a roadblock that's not making much sense to me.  I've written a integration test that makes use of the @TestFor annotation against a controller, but I'm getting very strange errors out of it.  Below is the test, stripped down to the minimum case that duplicates this issue:

```
import org.junit.*
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor

@TestFor(OrderController)
class OrderControllerIntegrationTests {

    public EndUser user

    @Before public void initialize() {
        user = new EndUser(username: UUID.randomUUID().toString(), password: "secret");
        user.save()
    }

    @Test public void get() {
        assert true
    }

    @Test public void create() {
        assert true
    }

}
```

In summary, the output I'm getting is that the save() method, in my test setup no longer exists for the second test in this class.  Which seems...pretty weird.

Here's the full output from grails test-app exampleapp.OrderControllerIntegrationTests:

```
Testsuite: exampleapp.OrderControllerIntegrationTests
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.769 sec
------------- Standard Output ---------------
--Output from get--
2012-05-15 22:35:03,491 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - begin

2012-05-15 22:35:03,493 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - current autocommit status: true

2012-05-15 22:35:03,493 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - disabling autocommit

2012-05-15 22:35:03,689 [main] DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into widget_user (id, version, password, username, class) values (null, ?, ?, ?, 'exampleapp.EndUser')

2012-05-15 22:35:03,970 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - rollback

2012-05-15 22:35:03,970 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - re-enabling autocommit

2012-05-15 22:35:03,970 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - rolled back JDBC Connection

--Output from create--
2012-05-15 22:35:03,979 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - begin

2012-05-15 22:35:03,979 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - current autocommit status: true

2012-05-15 22:35:03,979 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - disabling autocommit

2012-05-15 22:35:04,207 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - rollback

2012-05-15 22:35:04,207 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - re-enabling autocommit

2012-05-15 22:35:04,207 [main] DEBUG transaction.JDBCTransaction  - rolled back JDBC Connection

------------- ---------------- ---------------
------------- Standard Error -----------------
--Output from get--
--Output from create--
------------- ---------------- ---------------

Testcase: get took 0.51 sec
Testcase: create took 0.251 sec
    Caused an ERROR
No signature of method: exampleapp.EndUser.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: exampleapp.EndUser.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map)
    at exampleapp.OrderControllerIntegrationTests.initialize(OrderControllerIntegrationTests.groovy:17)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not `@Mock`ing your EndUser class so I'm not sure how you're even getting it to work for the first test.

I'd add the annotation to your class and see if that fixes it:

```
@TestFor(OrderController)
@Mock([EndUser])
class OrderControllerIntegrationTests{
```

Comment: Hi Ted-thanks for the reply.  This is an integration test, so I should have the full facilities of GORM/Hibernate and the DB, correct?  My understanding was that @Mock was specifically for unit testing with domain objects..not integration tests.

Comment: Ah, sorry, totally missed that the class name even had Integration in it.  Been doing too much unit testing in grails 2 :).  I'm going to change my answer around since what I've got doesn't make sense for your use case.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I don't think you're supposed to use the `@TestFor` annotation in integration tests, that ends up mocking things out that you don't need mocked because it's a real test.  I bet that's what's causing your issue and if you instead just `extend GroovyTestCase` your problem will go away.

Comment: Yup, removing the `@TestFor` and extending `GroovyTestCase` was exactly what needed to happen.  Perhaps I just missed it, but I don't remember seeing that in any of the docs on grails.org.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The @TestFor is for unit testing only.

You can inject the controller by doing the following

```
class OrderControllerIntegrationTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    OrderController orderController
    EndUser user

    @Before
    void initialize() {
        user = new EndUser(username: UUID.randomUUID().toString(), password: "secret");
        user.save()
    }
}
```